# Unsure how to solve this quadratic formula problem and how to expand and substitute into the formula

Tags: contest-math, quadratics

Find all values of a and b that will make $(ax+5)^2 = 16x^2 + bx + 25$ true for all $x$.

I believe that this is an equation that needs to be solved using the quadratic formula but am not sure how to expand and substitute into the formula. Any pointers/tips would be helpful.

Comment: Try to expand each side and compare term to term.

Comment: To be correct for all $x$, the two formulas must be identical. That means that the quadratic, linear and constant terms must be equal.

Answer (score 1):

If its true for all $x$, then its true for $x=1$ and $x=-1$. Evaluate those values of $x$, then sum the resulting equations and you will be able to solve for $a$. Then substitute the value of $a$ to solve for $b$.

Answer (score -1):

The quadratic formula is not needed here

\begin{align*}
(ax+5)^2 &= 16x^2 + bx + 25\\
\implies
b &= a^2 x- 16 x + 10 a \\
\implies  \mathbf{(ax+5)^2} &= 16x^2 + \bigg( a^2 x- 16 x + 10 a \bigg)x + 25\\
&=\mathbf{(ax+5)^2} 
\end{align*}

We can see from
$\quad (ax+5)^2=(ax+5)^2\quad $
how all values of $\space x\space$ require that $\quad  b = a^2 x- 16 x + 10 a  $.

On the other hand, expanding both sides and comparing coefficients,
$$a^2 x^2 + 10 a x + 25
=16x^2 + bx + 25\\
\implies\quad a=\pm4, \quad b=10a=\pm40$$

these results are easily verified in a spreadsheet. This is also confirmed by
\begin{align*} b &= a^2 x- 16 x + 10 a\\
&= 4^2 x- 16 x + 10\cdot 4\\
 &=40
\end{align*}

Comment: $a,b$ should be constants, not variables that depend on $x$.

Comment: @Calvin Lin    I believe I have shown that a,b cannot be constants unless $x=0.\quad$ I welcome correction if you can show how they "can" be constants for all values of $x\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I'm not sure how you went from the first line to the second. Can you elaborate? Perhaps you expanded $(ax+5)^2$ incorrectly? $\quad$ $ a = 4, b = 40 $ works. (Which is the solution to Alejandro's system of equations. Of course, we still have to verify that this is an identity of polynomials.)

Comment: @Calvin. I realized my mistake. Thanks